# Using webdriver and testng with apache metamodel for multiple excel sheets data as test input

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, apache-metamodel

Is there a possiblity of using primary key and foreign key for excel sheets using metamodel api to cook data for the testng tests in selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility for this using in the above mentioned context as Excel sheets can be queried by SQL/more-like SQL commands in [Fillo](http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/29)